# Run JPackage on a Windows Machine with FIPS

Tags: java, wix, fips, java-14

I am trying to run the new jpackage command that is bundled in Java 14 on a Windows 10 computer which is FIPS enabled. In order for Wix to work it needs the -fips command line option. Is there anyway I can pass that in from jpackage? Or is there any way I can set wix to always use the -fips option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this document -[Oracle - packaging-tool-user-guide.pdf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-tool-user-guide.pdf) which helped me fix the issue. I had created a main.wxs, test.wixproj, and overrides.wxs, but hadn't known to put them in a folder and pass in --resource-dir. All of those files just contain

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <FipsCompliant>true</FipsCompliant>
</PropertyGroup>
```

All 3 are probably not needed, but I haven't played with it much yet.

Comment: I am wondering how did you manage to run jpackage with such main.wxs and overrides.wxs (wxi?) passed as resource. I am getting errors like:
`The document element name 'PropertyGroup' is invalid.` 
And wixproj files are not supported based on the link you provided. 
I am facing similiar issue, but want to override `SuppressValidation` property and cannot get this to work.

Comment: Not sure if it helps at all, but this is the command I'm using to run jpackage - `jpackage.exe --input jpackage-base --main-jar lib\myjar.jar --resource-dir wix-resources --type app-image`. Inside wix-resouces I have main.xws, overrides.wxi, and test.wixproj. All 3 just have this `<PropertyGroup>
  <FipsCompliant>true</FipsCompliant>
</PropertyGroup> `